# Display new ViewController in TabBar View without removing TabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i have a UITabBarController with 5 Items. On one of these ViewController i have a Button, i'm gonna call it "start", so when i press start, i want to have another ViewController Pushed in, but still have the TabBar Visible.

if i use this code

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES]
```

the new ViewController hides the TabBar.

Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding as subview: `[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];`. Don't forget to set appropriate `frame` for subview.

And don't forget this:

> On iPhone and iPod touch devices, the view of modalViewController is always presented full screen. On iPad, the presentation depends on the value in the modalPresentationStyle property.

Comment: Okay thanks, this works, but how can i remove the view, or present the normal view controller if i click on the tabbaritem again?

Comment: In view controller that you want to dismiss call : `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [self pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
so tabBar will not hide

Comment: Isn't this for navigationcontroller only?

Comment: It is only if `UIViewController` is `UINavigationController`